# $\LaTeX$ macros for expectation, variance and covariance?

Tags: support, math-display

Is it possible for Stack Exchange to make available $\LaTeX$ abbreviations for `\mathrm{E}`, `\mathrm{Var}`, `\mathrm{Cov}` (possibly with new commands `\E`, `\Var` and `\Cov`)? The problem is that things like $\mathrm{Var}[X\mid Y]$ look much better than $Var[X\mid Y]$, but we end up losing a lot of time typing that.

Comment: Just FYI, you can also try: \$\text{Var}[X|Y]\$ (ie $\text{Var}[X|Y]$), if that's more convenient.

Comment: gung's suggestion saves two keystrokes, which is good, but I was wondering if `\Var` would make life easier for us. I understand that it would not be universally used, since it is not plain $\LaTeX$.

Comment: In my answers I often declare such a macro using `\newcommand` at the beginning and then use the macro in the rest of the answer. That's often helpful, especially if you need to use it many times.

Comment: (+1) Can I use `\newcommand` in my answers?!?!?!?!? Whoooaaaa! Problem solved. I'll setup a txt with definitions I normally use. Thank you a lot, Prof.!

Comment: @cardinal, I'm not familiar w/ `\newcommand`, since it seems that is the answer to this Q, can you make it official, perhaps w/ a brief tutorial re how it would work?

Answer (score 57):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$ $\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$ $\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$ $\newcommand{\Expect}{{\rm I\kern-.3em E}}$

Here is cardinal's solution. At the beginning of your answer type.

`$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$`

`$\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$`

`$\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$`

After that, just use it. For example:

$$
  \Var[X] = \E[\Var[X\mid Y]] + \Var[[\E\mid X]]
$$

$$
  \Cov[X,Y] = \E[XY] - \E[X]\E[Y]
$$

Stask suggested

`$\newcommand{\Expect}{{\rm I\kern-.3em E}}$`

$$\Expect[X]$$

which looks pretty.

Comment: A somewhat fancier solution is `$\newcommand{\Expect}{{\rm I\kern-.3em E}}$` that produces $\Expect[X]$. Unfortunately, you cannot easily extend it to the variance operator.

Comment: @Stas: That's an old hack for `\mathbb E`, i.e., $\mathbb E$. This does extend to variance $\mathbb V(X)$ or similar, as you like. The latter doesn't seem too popular though. :-)

Comment: Yay! Thanks, cardinal. I need to learn my $\LaTeX$ better, apparently :)

Comment: Neat solution. :) But I for one would prefer if these commands were available out-of-the-box.

Comment: (+1 a couple days ago) As a side note, if you want to avoid the empty space at the top of the answer caused by the macro definitions, you can just slip the `\newcommand` calls in at the beginning of the first math-mode block you use in your answer. :-)

Comment: (+1) Another great tip!

Comment: How do you use this? I have $\Var{\beta}$ but it misses those square brackets. How can you have them?

Comment: @Masi: `\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\operatorname{Var}\left[#1\right]}`

Comment: **Beware**  Although `\newcommand` is elegant and convenient, *it appears to affect all $\TeX$ markup on the entire page*--not just your individual post!  This raises the prospect of bad interactions arising from conflicting commands in different posts (and even in comments). I suspect their processing might depend on the sequence in which the posts appear on the page. Thus, both *arbitrary* and *future* developments beyond your control could ruin your post!

Answer (score 24):

To typeset an operator, it is much better to use `\operatorname` instead of `\mathrm`, as explained on tex.SE: [What's the difference between \mathrm and \operatorname?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname)

Compare (first line uses `\mathrm`, second line uses `\operatorname`):
$$\mathrm{Var}[x] + 2\mathrm{Var}[y] - \mathrm{E}[x]\mathrm{E}[y]$$
$$\operatorname{Var}[x] + 2\operatorname{Var}[y] - \operatorname{E}[x]\operatorname{E}[y]$$
and notice small white spaces *before* the operator name in the second line.

As noted by @cardinal, MathJax supports `\newcommand`. The best way to use it is to put into the formula where the operator first appears, because putting it into a separate formula creates an annoying empty line (see @Zen's answer). So whenever you first need variance, you can type `\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}`, e.g.

```
$$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}} \Var[x]+\Var[y]$$
```

and this will be displayed as

$$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}} \Var[x]+\Var[y]$$

All subsequent formulas can simply use `\Var` in them, e.g. `$\Var[z]$` will become $\Var[z]$.

Answer (score 17):

For Corr, Cov and Var I usually use `\DeclareMathOperator{\Corr}{Corr}`, which, done once in an answer, allows me to just write `\Corr(X,Y)` whenever I need it later, which displays:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Corr}{Corr} \Corr(X,Y)$$

Like Amoeba's answer, this ensures spacing is done correctly in a way that `\mathrm` doesn't. But see [newcommand vs. DeclareMathOperator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67506/newcommand-vs-declaremathoperator) on TEX.SE: Amoeba's answer apparently has the advantage that `newcommand` gives more flexibility.

But note I can still do `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E(X,Y)` and produce:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E(X,Y)$$

And of course I can reuse these in a later piece of $\LaTeX$ too: $\E(X)+\Corr(X,Y)$

(In a document `DeclareMathOperator` [can only be used in a preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238272/25866) but this doesn't seem to cause any difficulty on here.)

Comment: +1. This is perhaps a better way because it's slightly shorter: `\DeclareMathOperator{\Corr}{Corr}` vs. `\newcommand{\Corr}{\operatorname{Corr}}`.

Comment: This appealing answer; however, I've noticed that declaring operator through`\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}` prints`Cov` using the document font (Arial in my case), it would be more presentable if the `Cover` would be printed with the same font as the text generated via `\log` and other similar commands.