# Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated

Tags: support, faq, math-display

Questions formatted in LaTeX are easier to read, but not everyone who has permission to review a question/answer knows how to do it.

**Are there any instructions on CV about how to use LaTex**?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here are some options that I know of:

- There is a CV [help page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for the markdown options that the site supports.  That covers things like italics, and some (but very little) actual $\LaTeX$.
- There is a comprehensive 'tutorial' thread on [meta.Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) here: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
- One way to learn is to find something that uses $\LaTeX$ that you would like to also be able to do and right-click on it.  Then select `Show Math As -> TeX Commands`, and it will display the code that was used to create it.
- If you need to identify the $\LaTeX$ name / code for a symbol and you can draw it, [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) might help.
- Stack Exchange does have a [Q&A site dedicated to TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/); that might be helpful as well.
- After that, it's the broader internet; I've found [this MathJax documentation site](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to be very comprehensive and informative, but it's *really* slow to load.  [This webpage discovered by @Andre](https://web.archive.org/web/20140110233329/http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html) is less extensive, but loads *much* faster.  There's a handy 'reference card' [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304012339/http://elevatorlady.ca/doc/refcard/expressions.html).
- Lastly, I suppose you could ask a question about how to do something specific here (e.g.: [latex-macros-for-expectation-variance-and-covariance](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/)).

Comment: Today I learned the third bullet point!

Answer (score 6):

Probably the easiest option is offered in the Operations Research site's MathJax FAQ:

[How do I use MathJax on this site?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/372/51)

That answer lists three tools, the last one, MathPix, will convert a PDF to MathJax. After conversion little or no editing is required.

OR's FAQ isn't as huge as the one at Math.SE, but it is probably closer to statistics than the ones offered at [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/278) or other sites. If CV creates their own MathJax FAQ (which they should) they can provide links to the other sites MathJax FAQs at the end of the answer.