# Create template comments/answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment

Expecially when reviewing First Posts or answers which are flagged as Low Quality because they are too short, I need to rewrite more or less exactly the same comment *every time*. Hi, welcome, read the Tour, etc. Is there a way to save template comments/answers on Cross Validated? I could of course put all of them in a text file, but if I have it on my laptop, I won't be able to use it when out of home. I can put the file on the cloud, but I think such a feature would be a nice addition here...at least, I find template emails a fantastic help in Gmail, and maybe someone else would feel the same about templates here.

PS just got a new position in Data Science, also thanks to all the things I learned while asking & answering here! I know this is not the right place to say it, but I wanted to let the Community know :)

Comment: Have you seen https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2468? There is a long list of template comments and some advices on how to insert them effectively.

Comment: Congratulations on your new job, by the way!

Comment: thank you :D no, I haven't seen that question! I will check it out right now.

Comment: Also see: https://stackapps.com/search?q=%5Bcomments%5D+is%3Aquestion.

Comment: @AndreSilva are you able to use that [QuickComment2](https://stackapps.com/questions/6167/quickcomment2-automatic-keyboard-only-comment-snippets) app? I installed TamperMonkey under Chrome and it says the script is running, but pressing Alt+X while writing this (or other) comment doesn't bring up any snippet. It doesn't work! I will contact the developer, of course, but I'm curious to know if it works for you or anyone else.

Comment: @AndreSilva is there another one that you tried, and which works for you?

Comment: @AndreSilva my bad, QuickComment2 works, I accidentally installed the older version [QuickComment](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/Inferno/blob/master/nonmod/quickcomment/stackexchange-quickcomment.user.js). Anyway, in case you remember which extension you used, please let me know. Thanks!