# FAQ: How to search Crossvalidated

Tags: discussion, support

How to do effective search on Crossvalidated? Or, specific advice for how to search the web for statistics or machine learning?

---

The intention is to make a FAQ-style question, for layout we could emulate [this mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Then additions as new answers, which later can be incorporated (or edited directly if the answerer feels comfortable.)  But for a start, answers could be just for discussion about this FAQ proposal. I start below with a very basic outline.

---

1. **SE help page for search**: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching   (but I'm not sure if this is fully updated or comprehensive.)
2. **google or other external search engines can also be useful for site search**: copy `site:https://stats.stackexchange.com` into the search box in your browser, and add your search terms. This will also search in comments, which is left out from SE site search. This is often much faster than site search.

---

to be continued!

Comment: Related: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/best-practices-for-searching-cv

Comment: That thread isn't just related: it is identical and was created for exactly the same purpose.  If you would like to contribute to it -- or even improve the question part of it -- please feel free to do so!  The issue of searching the Web generally strikes me as being off topic here on CV Meta, though.

Comment: Maybe, but it has not been much  advertized, I managed to not see it before today!

Comment: No harm in a duplicate -- the dupe draws attention to the canonical question.

Comment: @whuber: Can I then edit the other thread into a more FAQ style, as the example I mentioned?

Comment: I believe you can just edit the original question.  As the author, I welcome your improvements.

Comment: @Sycorax That's right.  The main issue--and I believe we would all agree to this--is to keep all the answers together rather than splitting them across multiple threads.

Comment: @whuber: Is there some way we can edit a reference to that main thread inti the SE site search help page?

Comment: That dup so far has 246 views, needs more advertisement!