# Revisiting my incompletes

Tags: support, search

I have given good answers that I said I would like to wrap up, or revisit, or continue.

Here is an example:
[XGBoost Compared to Other Ensemble Methods Example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/494762/xgboost-compared-to-other-ensemble-methods-example/494833#494833)

How do I find all my answers where I had a "I want to go this way eventually"?  Is there a way to search for "to-do" in my answers?

Answer (score 7):

See [FAQ: Best Practices for Searching CV](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/faq-best-practices-for-searching-cv)  but here, if you said "I want to go this way eventually"  (or something like) *in the post itself*, not in a comment, you could try site search with

`user:me eventually`

or `user:me to-do`  and variants.  But if you might have said so **in comments**, site search do not see in comments, so then use google (or some other external engine) with

```
site:https://stats.stackexchange.com  EngrStudent  to-do
```

and experiment/modify if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you used the same phrase each time that you wrote about your intention to revisit an answer later, you could do a search like

`user:me I want to go this way eventually`

or similar; the code `user:me` restricts search hits to only posts you've written, and then you can include whatever search terms you like as normal.