# Nice $\LaTeX$ font for including function names or package names in questions

Tags: discussion

I have seen some nice $\LaTeX$ font for including function names or package names in questions. I cannot find any of them now and am looking for the name of the $\LaTeX$ font. This is probably not the best place to ask for it, sorry. (I have spent quite a bit of time searching for it on the $\TeX$ forum with no luck. I guess it should be there somewhere, but I just cannot find it...)

Comment: A typewriter font like $\texttt{this}$? But most people use the code markup like `this`.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica, I guess this is quite like what I meant. How is it called? And what is the $\LaTeX$ command for it?

Comment: @RichardHardy, when you see $\TeX$, you can right-click on it & select `Show Math As > TeX Commands` to see the latex code used to create it. Scortchi used `\texttt{}`. There is more here: [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/7290).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, this was helpful! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @RichardHardy.