# Why is it difficult to get help here

Tags: discussion, homework

I am Simran,  I have been studying for a govt exam with statistics as optional  (which is rarely opted by students ) , due to which there isn't any good  professional coaching available  , I have been studying on my own with help of internet .

Sometimes my doubts are resolved while sometimes not .

I took the help of this platform for a few  questions,  and in one of the question on vital statistics I wasn't able to do it even after the hint provided,  although I tried really hard to solve but couldn't.

I think in such a situation the other person could be a little considerate by looking at the efforts of other  , but no they aren't.

**Please tell me why ??**

I just want you to know  that I am preparing on my own without any teacher and not to solve any homework questions.

Comment: Our policies for self-study questions are listed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Someone you don't know and will not be rewarded for it in any real way took the time to read your question, and even gave you a hint. "Be a little considerate" is just not applicable here, they were more than considerate.

Comment: @simran SE is attempting an optimization strategy for increasing quality. It doesn't maximize everything good about Q&A, nor does it minimize everything bad about Q&A. But it does certain things quite well. You should use it for the things that it does well at, and use other resources for the things it does poorly at.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have asked 6 questions:

[why is hazard function tending to infinity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/529335/why-is-hazard-function-tending-to-infinity)
This has an answer by @AdamO which you haven't accepted. If you don't accept people's answers, or at least explain why their answer doesn't answer your question, they will be disinclined to answer again. The same goes if you don't upvote an answer that you find useful.

[Monte Carlo simulation for generating random numbers from a distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530589/monte-carlo-simulation-for-generating-random-numbers-from-a-distribution)
This was closed as off-topic although you did receive 2 answers (one of which you acccepted, so that is good)

[Rhods method of Logistic curve fitting y](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531251/rhods-method-of-logistic-curve-fitting-y)
This was closed due to needing more focus, although you got some good hints in the comments. I see that you have edited the question and I have just voted to re-open it.

[Population growth projection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531666/population-growth-projection)
The problem with this question is that you have just uploaded a picture. Please show some effort by using $\LaTeX$ to format the mathematics nicely. Having said that, you have received a very useful hint from @Ben. This is the best way to learn - by using hints, rather than getting someone to just tell you the whole answer.

[Complete expectation of life in Demography](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531810/complete-expectation-of-life-in-demography)
The same problem as the previous question. Please don't upload pictures.

[Mortality rate Calculations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531870/mortality-rate-calculations)
Same again, please don't upload pictures. For this one it takes hardly any longer to write it in $\LaTeX$ than by hand. I get that if you don't know $\LaTeX$ then it can be a bit time consuming at first but it is easy to learn and a useful skill to have (there is also a tex.stackexchange.com in case you have problems)

$ l_{45} = 30,450$
$ l_{46} = 30,320$
$ d_{45} = 30,450 - 30,320 = 130$
$ q_{45} = \frac{130}{30,450} = 0.0043$

If you do this, then people will be much more inclined to help. For example in these kinds of situations often there is a simple typo or missed step. If someone wants to answer then it is much easier to copy your $\LaTeX$ and edit it rather than type it all in from scratch. Plus, it looks a LOT nicer !!

Comment: Help for the variant of $\LaTeX$ used at this sites is at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Robert long , thank you sir , I will use your valuable advice to frame the upcoming questions

Comment: There is also information here: [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/7290).